# Adding data & time info of the record inserted. NOT BY USING INSERT STATEMENT

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a table `Employee` with columns: `Id, Name, Address, City, Createddate`

Now, I have to add this `createddate` column upon record insertion into the table, but NOT BY USING INSERT STATEMENT.

Is there any default option which adds up the date info when a row is being added to the table?

Suggest me in this regard.

Comment: Any particular reason for -1?

Comment: I think -1 (not mine) is because the question is so basic that it really shouldn't be asked. Its' basic of basics and reading manual doesn't hurt. That much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the default value of the field to `Getdate()`

Answer (score 2):

If not mistaken, when you create a table, you can let it place values automatically, like identity (Primary Key) or a datestamp. See example below:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[table] (
      tableID [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL
    , DatumCreate [datetime] DEFAULT GetDate() NOT NULL,
    , other values ....
    , CONSTRAINT pk_FactuurID PRIMARY KEY (FactuurID)
    ) 
GO
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can either use a *default value* (with `GetDate()`) as others have suggested, or, if you require more flexibility (e.g. to update the column) you can use a trigger to inspect the inserted values and set a column value directly.

Like this:

```
CREATE TRIGGER my_trigger
   ON  my_table
   AFTER INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE
AS 
BEGIN
    if exists(select * from inserted)
    -- we're covering just insert cases here..
    begin
       insert into my_table(col1, col2, col3, ..., col_timestamp) 
       select inserted.col1, inserted.col2...., CURRENT_TIMESTAMP from inserted
    end
END

GO
```

Comment: I dont want to create a trigger and addup maintenance for that also.. Is there any preperty While creating a table to default createddate to getdate() ?

Comment: @Pavan: yes - just use the default value as others have described.

Answer (score -2):

Well you don't have to use INSERT, but you may have to use CREATE

[MySQL timestamp](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/timestamp-initialization.html)

Comment: Oh, yeah...   Just testing your reflexes.